# Calcular fechas mensuales dada fecha emision y fecha vencimiento google sheets app script javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Cómo podrían orientarme para poder calcular las fechas mensuales de pago de n cantidad de pólizas, dada fecha emisión con la cual se calcula la fecha vencimiento (dado el plazo en meses 3, 6, 12, 18, 24 meses)?

Tengo el calculo de fechas de pago  en hoja google sheets,
[Suma de meses (dependiendo el plazo) a la fecha emision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9B1r.png),

esto es para un programa de seguimiento de pólizas el cual muestra el formulario Polizas por vencer
[una vez generado las fechas de cada mensualidad realizar la búsqueda dado un rango de fechas Desde-Hasta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCCLe.png).

Lo que pretendo realizar es, que en vez de generar en la hoja PLANES las nuevas pólizas que se vayan dando de alta y calculando las fechas mediante formulas, hacerlo mediante programación para no saturar el libro con mucha información.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.